# Add different references for entity with one action in .Net Core OData-Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, odata, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an entity which has an one-to-one relationship with different entities. To add/delete reference to one related entity I can use this `~/entityset/key/navigation/key/$ref` route-template from [official documentation](http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#03-02-built-in-routing-conventions) if I specify a route with `ODataRouteAttribute` like this:

```
[AcceptVerbs("POST", "DELETE")]
[ODataRoute("entity({entityId})/relatedEntity({relatedEntityId})/$ref")]
public IActionResult HandleRef([FromODataUri] Guid entityId, [FromODataUri] Guid relatedEntityId)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

It works for the one related entity I specify.

But since my entity has references to multiple other entities I hope that there is a more generic way solving that issue. Something like:

```
[ODataRoute("~/entityset/key/navigation/key/$ref")]
public IActionResult CreateRef([FromODataUri] Guid entityId, [FromODataUri] string navigation, [FromODataUri] Guid navigationId)
{
    // do generic stuff
}
```

Similar to this [microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/entity-relations-in-odata-v4#deleting-a-relationship-between-entities) for .Net Framework Version.